# Django - IntegrityError in terminal when migrating changes to a relationship field

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django model like the following..

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    related_user = models.ForeignKey(UserTypeA, related_name='related_example', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

where I recently had to make a change to the `related_user` field by changing the `ForeignKey` from `UserTypeA` to `UserTypeB`.

Of course, this raises an error in the terminal when I attempt to `python manage.py makemigration`...

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "models_examplemodel" violates foreign key constraint "models_examplemodel_related_user_id_ac0c6018_fk_accounts_"
DETAIL:  Key (related_user_id)=(13) is not present in table "accounts_usertypea".
```

What's the safest way to go about making these changes? Currently I'm in development so I'm happy to delete my data/migrations/whatever, but I imagine in production this would be difficult.

The ideal behaviour I'd like to see here is the relations from `ExampleModel` and `UserTypeA` just being deleted, and so the current relationships would be set to `NULL`. Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you already had data in your ExampleModel table before you updated the relationship from table UserTypeA to UserTypeB. The integrity error is absolutely correct in such cases.

The data which already exists in the table may have some keys or foreign key relation, which can not be mapped with the new table (or does not exist in the newly mapped table).

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Indeed, I did expect the integrity error to occur and so was wondering if there's any way to alter this default behaviour? i.e. would it be something that I would write a script to resolve this sort of problem in production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you simply want to drop `UserTypeA` and use `UserTypeB` with `None` values simply do this:

- remove `related_user` field
- generate migrations
- add `related_user` field
- generate migrtions

If you want to do something more complecated (fill `UserTypeB` based on `UserTypeA`) these are the steps

- add `realted_user_b` field with default as null
- generate migration file
- write a data migrations file which fills `realted_user_b` based on current data [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)
- remove `realted_user` field
- generate migration file
- rename `realted_user_b` to `realted_user`
- generate migration file

Comment: I tried the first option but migrating after removal of the field still generates the same error unfortunately

Comment: you have to first remove field then generate migrations file then add new field then generate final migration file again. If you simply update field and generate migration file django thinks that you have updated the field (doesn't drop old column). but the old column may contain invalid data so by doing as I said (generating 2 migrations files) you force django to drop old column

Comment: still getting the same error unfortunately, should i remove some migrations files?

Comment: fixed it! this worked except that i had to delete all of the most recent migration files up to (and including) the point where the migrations stopped working